# Extract rows group by unique column values in a for loop. Multiple outputs in Matlab

Tags: matlab, for-loop, unique

Let say I have a table

```
Name = {'Ann';'Joe';'Bob';'Mary';'Katy','John','Lee'};
Age = [13,17,13,17,15,15,15];
Weight = [100,160,160,124],142,112,142];
Grade = [73,99,50,64,88,45,76];
```

I want to use a for loop (the real data is much larger), and group by each unique value in the "age" column and output different tables with same values.
In this case, if we group by age, one table with Ann and Bob (Age 13), a second table with Joe and Mary, and the third table with Katy, John, and Lee.

So far, I know how to do it when the groups are small (not many tables), but how to do it when I have a lot of unique values to group them in?

```
group = findgroups(data.Age);
group2 = group(:,1) == 2;
data_group2 = data(group2,:);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `unique` function to get all the unique age values, then run a for loop over these.

```matlab
Name = {'Ann','Joe','Bob','Mary','Katy','John','Lee'};
Age = [13,17,13,17,15,15,15];
Weight = [100,160,160,124,142,112,142];
Grade = [73,99,50,64,88,45,76];

age_groups = unique(Age);
tables = {};

for i = 1:length(age_groups)
    indices = Age == age_groups(i);
    tables{i} = table(categorical(Name(indices)).', Age(indices).', Weight(indices).', Grade(indices).','VariableNames',{'Name','Age','Weight','Grade'});
end
```

Then you can access each of the tables like so:

```matlab
>> tables{1}

ans =

  2×4 table

    Name    Age    Weight    Grade
    ____    ___    ______    _____

    Ann     13      100       73  
    Bob     13      160       50  

>> tables{2}

ans =

  3×4 table

    Name    Age    Weight    Grade
    ____    ___    ______    _____

    Katy    15      142       88  
    John    15      112       45  
    Lee     15      142       76
```